# Uniformly-spaced histogram bins with dc.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Mike Bostock uses the following snippet to generate uniformly-spaced bins for a histogram:

```
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
.bins(x.ticks(20))
(values);
```

[source](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450)

Is there any way to adapt this to a project that uses dc.js and crossfilter.js?

Essentially, I want to dynamically generate the bins and then use the chart to filter on a particular attribute. Total newbie to this. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

dc.js supports histograms via crossfilter. Use a group for your bar chart that looks something like this:

```
var binwidth = 0.2;
var dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.x; });
var group = dim.group(function(d) { return binwidth * Math.floor(d.x/binwidth); });
```

This tells crossfilter to use keys binwidth apart.

And initialize the bar chart with these units:

```
chart.xUnits(dc.units.fp.precision(binwidth));
```

Comment: Peharps a missing binwidth.  

`var group = dim.group(function(d) { return binwidth*Math.floor(d.x/binwidth); });`

Comment: I have coded 2 examples on how to code a threshold histogram. It illustrates that one should code the thresholds (that you may need) in the dimension function not in the group function: jsfiddle.net/PBrockmann/dwoycwrp (thresholds set on dimension) to compare to jsfiddle.net/PBrockmann/ma3wr55k (thresholds set on group). The first one is the correct one if you want to retrieve values that have been threshoded in the first and last bins.

Comment: @Gordon, is it possible to calculate sum of a different variable(dim.group.reduceSum)  as opposed to the count (dim.group)?

Comment: @anmolkoul, sure, why not? All of these steps are before reduction, so you should be able to apply any reduction to the group that you want.