# crossfilter.js - exclude facts from group based on separate dimension

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, dc.js, crossfilter

Presume I have the following crossfilter object (simplified) to be plotting in a dc.js scatterPlot

```
var ndx = crossfilter([
  {time: 0.5, counts: 8, direction: 1},
  {time: 0.8, counts: 0, direction: -1},
  {time: 1.0, counts: 8, direction: 1},
  {time: 1.2, counts: 1, direction: -1},
  {time: 1.8, counts: 10, direction: 1},
  {time: 2.0, counts: 2, direction: -1},
  {time: 2.2, counts: 14, direction: 1},
  {time: 2.5, counts: 0, direction: -1},
  ...
]);
```

How do I setup a crossfilter such that the output vectors are

```
x --> [0,1,2,...] 
y --> [8,9,14,...] // (average of all "1" direction transition counts, per whole integer time)
```

What I have so far is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29452543/12728698)

```
const timeDim = ndx.dimension(d => d.time);
const binwidth = 1;
const timeHist = timeDim
  .group(d => {
    return binwidth * Math.floor(d / binwidth);
  })
  .reduceCount(); // I believe this only gives sum, but haven't gotten to averaging yet
```

Which works when I don't care about excluding *direction: -1*, all attempts to do so have broken my crossfilter, e.g.

```
const timeSignalDim = ndx.dimension(d => {
    if (d.direction === 1) {
      return d.time;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using reductio... based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641350/dc-js-bar-chart-on-subset-of-data?rq=1)

```
const binwidth = 1;
const timeDim = ndx.dimension(d => d.time);
const timeSignalGroup = reductio()
  .count(true)
  .sum(d => d.counts)
  .avg(true)
  .filter(d => {
    return d.direction === 1;
  })(
  timeDim.group(d => {
    return binwidth * Math.floor(d / binwidth);
  })
);
```

And accessed the values via valueAccessor fxn

```
...
.valueAccessor(d => {
  return d.value.avg;
})
```

Very happy to entertain any more elegant answers!

Answer (score 1):

Every path in your dimension and group functions must return a value, otherwise the default return value in Javascript is `undefined`, which [can cause crossfilter to go off the deep end](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#natural-ordering-of-dimension-and-group-values).

Also, there is no way to reject a row in the dimension or group key functions. Instead you must reduce rejected rows to zero:

```
const timeDim = ndx.dimension(d => d.time);
const binwidth = 1;
const timeHist = timeDim
  .group(d => {
    return binwidth * Math.floor(d / binwidth);
  })
  .reduceSum(d => d.direction > 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

This will count all positive direction. It is equivalent to reductio's `.filter()` in your answer.

Reductio is very elegant, but just for comparison, and because I started answering this before you posted your answer, the straight crossfilter way to calculate an average is

```
.reduce(
  (p,v) => { // add
    p.sum += v.counts;
    p.count++;
    return p;
  },
  (p,v) => { // remove
    p.sum -= v.counts;
    p.count--;
    return p;
  },
  () => ({sum: 0, count: 0}));
```

Tell the chart to calculate the ratio when reading the value:

```
chart.valueAccessor(({value: {sum,count}}) => sum / count);
```

Combining that with skipping direction < 0:

```
.reduce(
  (p,v) => { // add
    if(v.direction > 0) {
      p.sum += v.counts;
      p.count++;
    }
    return p;
  },
  (p,v) => { // remove
    if(v.direction > 0) {
      p.sum -= v.counts;
      p.count--;
    }
    return p;
  },
  () => ({sum: 0, count: 0}));
```

[Test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/vro254hx/10/).

Again, reductio is doing pretty much the same thing underneath. Your choice if you want to work with the slick EDSL or directly with crossfilter.

Comment: your answers are always awesome! Thanks, upvoted for the helpfulness, but accepted the reductio version considering its way simpler for me... I am interested in more complicated crossfilter operations, do you know of any good blog posts/tutorials for crossfilter custom reducer functions? I've looked at the api docs and it's pretty dense

Comment: As far as I know, SO answers are the best documentation. In lieu of comprehensive documentation, I try to make each of my answers explain a little more than is necessary for the task at hand. (I’ve never had time to write a book. ;) The [crossfilter gotchas wiki](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas) and [dc.js tutorials](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki#books-and-tutorials) are good too. Let me know if you find good resources out there!